# container is taking the size of card but i want to make it small?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Card(
                    elevation: 7.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /4,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle
                      ),
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage('asset/download.jpg'),

                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Always add details to your questions, this makes it easy for readers to understand what you want to do. Just a simple code and a title are not enough.

I assume you want to add another item next to the container. For that you can try to add row or column inside the card and then add the container.

```
Card(
  elevation: 7.0,
  color: Colors.white,
  child: new Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle
        ),
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('asset/download.jpg'),
        ),
      )
    ]
  ),
)
```